# Questions about the Backpropogation Algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, neural-network, backpropagation

I have a few questions concerning backpropogation. I'm trying to learn the fundamentals behind neural network theory and wanted to start small, building a simple XOR classifier. I've read a lot of articles and skimmed multiple textbooks - but I can't seem to teach this thing the pattern for XOR.

Firstly, I am unclear about the learning model for backpropogation. Here is some pseudo-code to represent how I am trying to train the network. [Lets assume my network is setup properly (ie: multiple inputs connect to a hidden layer connect to an output layer and all wired up properly)].

```
SET guess = getNetworkOutput() // Note this is using a sigmoid activation function.
SET error = desiredOutput - guess
SET delta = learningConstant * error * sigmoidDerivative(guess)
For Each Node in inputNodes
   For Each Weight in inputNodes[n]
      inputNodes[n].weight[j] += delta;

// At this point, I am assuming the first layer has been trained.
// Then I recurse a similar function over the hidden layer and output layer.
// The prime difference being that it further divi's up the adjustment delta.
```

I realize this is probably not enough to go off of, and I will gladly expound on any part of my implementation. Using the above algorithm, my neural network *does* get trained, kind of. But not properly. The output is always

```
XOR 1 1 [smallest number]
XOR 0 0 [largest number]
XOR 1 0 [medium number]
XOR 0 1 [medium number]
```

I can never train the [1,1] [0,0] to be the same value.

If you have any suggestions, additional resources, articles, blogs, etc for me to look at I am very interested in learning more about this topic. Thank you for your assistance, I appreciate it greatly!

Comment: Do you use at least 2 hidden neurons? How do you initialize the weights?

Comment: Weights are initialized randomly and I am using at least 2 hidden neurons. I believe my problem is the backpropogation mathematics that I am employing. I think I need to focus on making the error calculation more mathematically correct.

Answer (score 2):

Ok. First of all. Backpropagation as it states work from back. From output through all hidden layers up to input layer. The error which is counted in last layer is "propagated" to all previous ones. So lets assume you have model of type: input - 1 hidden layer - output. In first step you count error from desired value and one you have. Then you do backprop on weights between hidden and output. And after that you do backprop for weights between input and hidden. In each step you backprop error from next to previous layer, simple. But maths can be confusing ;) Please take look at his short chapter for further explanation: http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/rojas/neural/chapter/K7.pdf

Comment: Thank you much, d3r0n! That article trumps everything else I've read. Although I have yet to solve my problem, I do realize that the math I was using is entirely off. I need to re-read that pdf a bit more and I think I'll have it! Thanks again :)